# Is there a function to get push notifications in flutter? For example Facebook or Whatsapp notifications

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wanting to develop an app similar to 'Notiduino' where it takes android notifications such as whatsapp message notifications or missed calls and retrieve them within the app. Is there any lib for this function? I searched and found nothing ...
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Overlay widgets. Combining them with a little bit of animation will give you effective UI. One example [here](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/06/how-to-create-a-toast-or-notifications-notion-of-overlay/) and another is [here](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-adding-animated-overlays-to-your-app-e0bb049eff39).

You can also use [Firebase in-app notification](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging). Using Firebase in-app notification has one more advantage. You can also send push notifications from the same firebase project. Of course, relevant settings have to be made. Having said that, there are a bunch of web pages which will guide you through the step by step process.

Comment: But can firebase get notifications from other applications? Because I can only send notifications by him ...

Comment: Absolutely. All you will have to do is to call a REST end-point. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57352471/1367159)