# How to send push notification via Lambda by Firebase using Python

Tags: python, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification from Firebase Cloud Message via AWS Lambda. The API responds with authorization error.

import requests
import json

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Message']
    tokens = event['PushNotificationTokens']
    for token in tokens:
        data = {"notification": { "title": "My Awesome App", "body": message,}, "to": token}
        data_json = json.dumps(data)
        print(data_json)
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'AAAA…...0HuQH'}

    url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'    

    response = requests.post(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)

    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.content)
    print(jsonResponse)


    return jsonResponse
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything is perfect - except the headers. You'll have to add 'Key=' before the actual key. See the code below :

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'Key=AAAA…...0HuQH'}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I thought the 'Authorization' head should only consists the actual key. So, I had deleted the word 'Key=' earlier.