# How to send fcm notification using flutter and firebase realtime database

Tags: function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

i am trying to do firebase realtime messaging code in node.js,but i am confuce about how to do that?
 const doc = snap.data()
    console.log(doc)

```
const idFrom = doc.idFrom
const idTo = doc.idTo
const messageId =context.params.messageId
// Get push token user to (receive)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you clear, you can reference this repo has 86 stars https://github.com/jlcvp/fcm-node 
A Node.JS simple interface to Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for Android & iOS & Web Notification and data push

Another reference document https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/#step-2-send-messages-with-nodejs-backend

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a simple REST call to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. You'll need to provide authorisation key in the header. The auth key can be derived from the Firebase portal. See [here](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3) on how to set it up in Postman and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57352282/1367159) post gives an equivalent code in Python.